# Intellij VCS auto update on application start

Tags: intellij-idea

Any idea if it's possible to update my project when I open Intellij?

I found the VCS background configuration but none of the options seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You have to manually pull to fetch changes. There is a button in the top right-hand side with a blue arrow and the word `VCS` on it. A few fewer clicks than using the menu pull downs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I was looking for a way to avoid forgetting to update before coding. Would it work if I build a plugin for that? Or is there any limitation?

Comment: you could make a feature request